# Is the definition of subbasis well-defined?

Tags: general-topology

There are more definitions of **subbasis** in general topology. I chose the one that seams me to be the simplest:

**Definition.** Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space.  A **subbasis** of $\tau$ is a subset $B\subseteq\tau$ that generates the topology T. This means that $\tau$ is the smallest topology containing $B$ (any topology $\tau'$ on $X$ containing $B$ must also contain $\tau$).

**Note.** From my understanding such a definition can be made only after proving that the smallest topology containing $B$ is something well-defined and unique. I mean: not all topologies containing $B$ have to be comparable. We can consider $S:=\{\tau:B\subseteq \tau \text{ and $\tau$ is a topology of $X$}\}$, but then we have to prove that $S$ has a minimum.

> How can I formulate a Lemma that legitimates the definition above? Or, if such a lemma is not needed, why is it not needed?

Why in topology the word *collection of elements* is so often used instead of subset?

Comment: Lemma: Let $\mathscr{T}$ be a family of topologies on a set $X$. Then $\bigcap \mathscr{T}$ is a topology on $X$.

Comment: The "smallest topology on $X$ containing $B$" is the intersection of all topologies on $X$ that contain $B$. Call this intersection $\omega$. Clearly, if $\tau$ is a topology on $X$ containing $B$, then $\omega \subset \tau$. Also, I think the term "collection of elements" is used sometimes instead of "subset" just to spice things up or because it sometimes seems slightly more clear.

Comment: I've already proved the Lemma!

Comment: @PeptideChain If you've already proven the lemma, then it's immediate to see that the intersection of _all_ topologies that contain $B$ is the smallest topology which contains $B$.

Comment: @Arthur: thank you. The problem is almost always to connect the different things

Comment: @Arthur: another aspect is that I had to choose the order of the structure of my notes: first subbasis or first lattice of topologies. For the lattice of topologies I have the lemma "the intersection of topologies is a topogy" but also I needed the concept of "topology generated from the union of topologies", and subbasis was just in the middle of the two. Now I have to put 1) intersection 2) subbasis 3) lattice (intersection + union)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma:** Let $X$ be a set and let $S$ be a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$. Then, among all topologies in $X$ there is one and only one topology $\tau$ such that:

1. $\tau\supset S$;
2. if $\tau^\star$ is a topology in $X$ and $\tau^\star\supset B$, then $\tau^\star\supset\tau$.

**Proof:** Let $\mathcal T$ be the set of all topologies in $X$ which contain $B$. Then $\mathcal{T}\neq\emptyset$, since $\mathcal{P}(X)\in\mathcal T$. Let $\tau=\bigcap_{T\in\mathcal T}T$. Then $\tau$ is a topology and $\tau\supset B$. Besides, it follows from the definition of $\tau$ that, if $\tau^\star$ is a topology in $X$ and if $\tau^\star\supset B$, then $\tau^\star\supset\tau$.

Comment: Here $\subset$ is the weak version, i.e. $\subseteq$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For any set of topologies $\{\tau_I\}$, their intersection $\bigcap_I \tau_I$ is also a topology.